# Get data from other table DB when i use add_action 'user_register' (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Excuse me, want to ask,
I have tried to use this script in function.php:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );
```

And it worked
I want to retrieve the referral id data in the wp_uap_affiliates table.
But I realized that the add_action above runs before there is an insert process into the wp_uap_affiliates table, so I can't get the referral id.

Does anyone have a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using any plugin for affiliates?

Comment: @ShaikhAejazAhmed Yes, i'm using Ultimate Affiliate Pro plugin

Answer (score 1):

Because add_action is earlier than inserting the referral id into the database, so I'm trying to find something like do_action in the Ultimate Affiliate Pro plugin script.

Then I found this code:

```
do_action('uap_on_register_action', $this->user_id);
```

Then I use 'uap_on_register_action' to replace 'user_register' in my add_action.

So this is the code after replace:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );
```

Now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I checked it's indeed updating table after that hook. can you please give a try below code in user_register hook ?

```
             sleep(3);
             global $indeed_db;
             $affiliate_id = $indeed_db->get_affiliate_id_by_wpuid($user_id);
```

Comment: Hi @Shaikh Aejaz Ahmed, sorry for my delay response.. Actually i have use that script in my function.php, and it work. But the problem is that script running before the affiliate_id inserted in DB. So that i get empty data. Fyi, i have set the priority from 99 to 20000 but it same.

Comment: Why & when you want affiliate Id ? As soon as user register ? Or you want affiliate Id for some other thing ?

Comment: I want to retrieve some user data who just signed up (including affiliate id) to send to other platforms using API

Comment: Once I got stuck in same scenario where the entry happen after few seconds so I used sleep(3); function within my function. In this way my code wait for 3 sec to execute next lines & within that time wordpress created the entry in databse & I got that...... I might be wrong as well but can you give a try ? Also, I see that there is filter when assigning affiliate Id in plugin can you use the filter & get user id from affiliate Id & do the stuff..... After that return same affiliate Id.

Comment: Thank you Shaikh to help me thinking. Now my problem is solved. You can check my answer